# Getting Error AccessDenied while upload file in S3 from Laravel-5.7

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, laravel-5.8

I am facing problem while **uploading** any file on **S3 Server**. but the same configuration is working on a different project. No concept changed and no any configuration changed. I am working on **Laravel 5.8** version. I am sharing code and Error please tell me why it is coming?

Error

> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://coxxxxx.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/uploadFiles/pdf/2222222/2222222_COLLEGE_DETAILS_1569831261.pdf"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://colxxxxx.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/uploadFiles/pdf/2222222/2222222_COLLEGE_DETAILS_1569831261.pdf` resulted in a `403 Forbidden`
>
> `AccessDenied`Access Denied3E7C4E (truncated...)
>    AccessDenied (client): Access Denied -

**FileSysrems.php**

```
  's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL')      
    ],
```

**For Uplaod on S3**

```
    $s3Path ="uploadFiles/pdf/2222222/2222222_COLLEGE_DETAILS_1569831261.pdf";     
    $binary_data = base64_decode($file);
    $pathS3 =Storage::disk('s3')->put($s3Path, $binary_data,'public');
```

Comment: Have you added the AWS env values to your `.env`

Comment: i am also facing this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this problem because Admin created multiple buckets on a single account. when he divided into different account then everything starts working.

Another way is check your **Bucket access ( Public /  private)**. if your bucket is private then remove **'public'** from code

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('path','file'); //code is like this.
```

Comment: problem was gone solve as i told in my case .so why i got down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing accesses to your S3 bucket from IAM.
It worked for me once I updated correct access.