# Laravel-Mediable library is not working with s3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, media

I am trying to upload images on S3 bucket using Laravel 8, but it's not uploading with this library I tried with other libraries and for them I am able to upload images on S3,

Here is the error screenshot which I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSS6e.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution of my problem, my S3 bucket was a private one that's why it was not accessible in order to access private I added this link.

$media = $mediaUploader->fromSource($image)->makePrivate()->toDisk('s3')->upload();

This article helped me: [Getting Error AccessDenied while upload file in S3 from Laravel-5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164281/getting-error-accessdenied-while-upload-file-in-s3-from-laravel-5-7)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you donot have access to upload images on S3 bucket.

Please follow this to get it resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098327/4227367